# Matlab: Terminate a function from another function

Tags: matlab

I have a function A which will calls on function B, from function B I want to terminate function A.
The main issue is that function B can only run if function A does not run.
I know there is no script like version for ctr+c, but this is not what I want as it's not the function itself that needs to be terminated but a different function. Is there a way to do this?

```
**function A**

B(varargin)

end

**function B(varargin)**

kill_function_A

some more statements

end
```

Let me revise this so it is more clear:

```
**function A**
if some_statement_is_true
B(varargin)
end
much more code

**function B(varargin)**
terminate A
update A (this is the reason why it needs to be terminated)
A (restart A, since it is now updated, I can terminate B within A if it is active)
end
```

Do note that A needs to be terminated before B is able to run. so "B; return" is not possible.
(Thanks so far for all the answers)

Comment: This is not possible. Any method to exit function A will exit B as well and return to the caller of A.

Comment: If I may ask, what do you need this for? It is [a bit smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) if you ask me...

Comment: "update A" seems to indicate that A has a global state, so you're using global variables, is that correct?

Comment: Can you create a [self contained example](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you are trying to do? Generally you use `return` to terminate a function, or throw an `error`, and if that doesn't fit it is worth taking a step back and look at the design of the program. Is it a case of the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you really want is to not execute statements in `A` after the call to `B` (if required). This is easily done with the following code.

```
function A

terminate = B;
if terminate == true
    return
end

end

function terminate = B

terminate = true;

end
```

Comment: A valid workaround, but a constant return is somehow strange. Function A could be reduced to `B;return` if terminate is always true.

Comment: @DanielR: Just an example ; I'm assuming the OP will set `terminate` to `false` if he does not want to end `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
function A
if some_statement_is_true
  B(varargin)
  return
end
much more code

function B(varargin)
  update A (this is the reason why it needs to be terminated)
  A (restart A, since it is now updated, I can terminate B within A if it is active)
end
```

It would not "stop" `A`, but effectively `A` would be doing nothing else than calling `B`, which should result in the more or less same outcome.
Alternatively you should maybe run `B` and update `some_statement_is_true`:

```
function A

while some_statement_is_true
  B(varargin);
  some_statement_is_true = ...; % make sure this gets updated
end
much more code

function B(varargin)
  update A;
end
```

**EDIT:**

If A is a standalone .exe, you could do as follows, to stop and run the new version:

```
function A
if some_statement_is_true
  B(varargin);
  exit();
end
much more code

function B(varargin)
  update A;
  system('A.exe');
end
```

I've successfully used this scheme for self-updating applications, that needed a MATLAB restart.

Comment: Nope. A really needs to be terminated. B needs to update the script (i.e. the .m (or in this case the .exe as standalone) file itself) not just some variable. The only way of updating a file is when it is not running.

Comment: Wether `A` is from a standalone .exe or a .m-file makes quite a difference. For a standalone exe you could simply issue a `system` call to the now updated .exe and `exit()` the current matlab session.